# Ruby-Mp3Info error when saving/closing a file

Tags: ruby

I've upgraded to the new mp3info GEM and now there seems to be a problem when it comes to writing the changes to the MP3 tags.  Ruby version 1.9.3, mp3info version 0.8.4, Windows 7 - 64 bit.

Simple program:

```
require 'mp3info'
mp3 = Mp3Info.open('a.mp3')
mp3.title = 'bogo'
mp3.close
```

Results in:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - (./.a.mp3.tmp, a.mp3)
from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-mp3info-0.8.4/lib/mp3info.rb:453:in `rename'
from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-mp3info-0.8.4/lib/mp3info.rb:453:in `close'
from (irb):6
from D:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I've checked permissions on the file/folder, and I'm running as Administrator in the CMD shell.

Comment: Both files exist in the directory, so presumably this is because the target file already exists?

Comment: but File.rename WILL overwrite an existing file, so this has to be something like an open file handle, no?

Comment: Addendum:
I've checked to see if there's a file handle open, and "a.mp3" is open.
If I enter the `File.rename('.a.mp3.tmp', 'a.mp3')` command after the Mp3Info.open command it generates the same error.
If I enter a different target filename.  The rename operation succeeds.  
If I enter the `File.rename('.a.mp3.tmp', 'a.mp3')` without running the Mp3Info.open command, it succeeds.

Comment: I installed an older version of Ruby-mp3info (0.6.16) and the error doesn't occur.

Comment: But now I get the encoding character set error, which was why I wanted the latest version in the first place.

Comment: In meantime (Mp3Info::VERSION=0.8.7) you need a `mp3info.tag.title  =`. But the problem with the open file handle still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

### Obsolete since ruby-mp3info version 0.8.8

This answer is obsolete since ruby-mp3info version 0.8.8

---

I think  it is a bug in [mp3info](https://github.com/moumar/ruby-mp3info), (I checked the actual version 0.8.7).

The method `Mp3Info#close` does not always close the internal io.

If you modify mp3info.rb like this:

```
###>>>Approx line 370:
# Flush pending modifications to tags and close the file
# not used when source IO is a StringIO
def close
....
  end
  #####   ###aprox line 465
  @io.close unless @io.closed?  ## <<<< add this.
  #####
end
```

then the problem was solved for me.

---

This bug was reported and corrected in a [pull request](https://github.com/moumar/ruby-mp3info/pull/63). The [ruby-mp2info-gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-mp3info) version 0.8.8 (January 26, 2016 ) contains this correction.

Comment: Update: The [Pull request](https://github.com/moumar/ruby-mp3info/pull/63) is merged.